# finding smallest two nodes in a linked list in c

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to find the smallest two numbers in a linked list in C++ (without using any built-in functions).

I tried to do so as below:

**My logic is:**

(1) Assume the first node in the linked list is `minimum1` and the second is `minimum2`. Compare them. The greater becomes `minimum2` and the smaller becomes `minimum1`.

(2) Start from the third node (third because we have already covered first and second) in a while loop until we reach `NULL`, thus traversing all the list.

(3) Compare the newly traversed node with `minimum1` and `minimum2`. If this node is smaller than `minimum1`, then put its value in `minimum1`. `minimum2` now will contain the value of `minimum1`, and `minimum1` will contain the value of the newly found node which was smaller than `minumum1`.

Below is my code which takes the number of nodes to be created, reads the values of all nodes continuously (just keep on pressing **Enter** after every number), and creates the linked list from all the nodes. These are working fine.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int freq;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node* tree;

// Finding minimum two elements:
void find_two_min(node** List, node** lmin1, node** lmin2)
{
    int i;
    node* temp = *List;
    node *min1, *min2;
    node* var1 = *List;
    node* second = (*List)->next;
    if (var1 > second)
    {
        min2 = var1;
        min1 = second;
    }
    else
    {
        min1 = var1;
        min2 = second;
    }
    while (temp->next->next->next != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->freq < min2->freq)
        {
            min1 = min2;
            min2 = temp;
        }
        else if (temp->freq < min1->freq)
        {
            min1 = temp;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    *lmin1 = min1;
    *lmin2 = min2;
}

void main()
{
    int size, data;
    node *min1, *min2;
    int count = 0; // This flag is to check whether it's the first node inside the do-while loop.
    tree = NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    node* prev;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &data);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            node* temp;
            temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
            tree = prev;
        }
        else
        {
            node* temp;
            temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        --size;
        ++count;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list:\n");
    node* temp1;
    temp1 = tree;
    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", temp1->freq);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    node* temp5 = tree;
    find_two_min(&temp5, &min1, &min2);
    printf("\nThe two minimum numbers are min1: %d and min2: %d.\n", min1->freq, min2->freq);
}
```

My code doesn't work on the following input (it gives the wrong output):

```
Enter the number of nodes:
4
Enter the elements:
0
-5
-2
8
Printing linked list:
0, -5, -2, 8,
The two minimum numbers are min1: 0 and min2: -5.
```

It was supposed to print "min1: -5" and "min2: -2" but I don't know why it doesn't.

Could anyone please help me eliminate this problem? Any algorithm or piece of code in C/C++ to use as a reference is appreciated. Thanks.

Note: I can't use any built-in functions.

Comment: 1. Sort list in increasing order.  The first two nodes will be your minima.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: sorting is `O(N . log N)` while his logic solves it in `O(N)` , or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two ints min1, min2, both INT_MAX (from limits.h). (Assumption: No element can have the value INT_MAX.)

Walk through your list, one by one. For each element do:

---

If it is smaller than min1 then min1 is now the second smallest ever, so assign min1 to min2. Then replace min1 with the element.
If it is not smaller than min1 but smaller than min2, it replaces min2.
If none of the above, skip element.

---

After iterating the list min1 will hold the smallest list value, min2 the second smallest. If min2 is INT_MAX, the list had only one element. If min1 is INT_MAX, the list was empty.

Comment: Thanks it worked but still a don't know why we assigned INT_MAX to min1 and min2 ?What does they contain? I tried to google it but couldn't understand it. what does it do, Do you know any other alternative to achieve the same target ?

Comment: When looking for min, it is logical to initialize your temp variables with something that all other values will be smaller then, guaranteeing that the min came out of the list, and not your initialization.  Consider what would happen if you initialized min1 to INT_MIN

Comment: Oh, INT_MAX is just the biggest value an int can hold. Remember that int has the "natural" integer size on a machine, so it would be 16 int on a 16 bit machine, 32 bits on a i386 and possibly 64 bits on an x64 architecture, although all three are just possibilities. The standard doesn't dictate a particular size. You can imagine that the biggest values they can hold are quite different. INT_MAX holds that biggest implementation dependent value for any given implementation, i.e. it's different  from machine to machine, compiler to compiler or from flag to flag for the same compiler/machine.

Comment: Hmmm :-) I realized that for a good grade I need to improve my algorithm: If the minimal value is replaced, the old minimal becomes the second smallest! Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If trying to do 2 things at once confuses you,

> > > > then do only 1 thing,

AND LATER, follow that with another singular effort.

i.e.

1st - write search1() to find the smallest item and record the node pointer.

2nd - write search2() to find the smallest item, but add to your search2 the idea to compare the node address to the previously found smallest node.  And when already found, skip it as if was not even there.

---

Implement search1, debug it, and get that working.

---

AFTER THAT

Implement search2, (probably a copy)  and pass in the node pointer found in the search1.
Each time you find a possible update to the search2's smallest node, 
insert a test to determine if this node matches the previously found

Comment: i jut tried to do what you said (finding sepeartely) but i still gives wrong output.  The two minimumnumbers are  min1 :-1074189952   and min2 : -5

Comment: So, you could not find min1.  If you do not know debugger, then try using output (via cout or cerr) to debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in the line

```
if(var1>second)
```

This is comparing the *memory addresses* of the two nodes, not their frequencies!

There's another bug in the line

```
    if(temp->freq<min2->freq)
```

and the later line

```
    else if(temp->freq<min1->freq)
```

The code inside the `if` statement block following the first line behaves as though you compared `temp->freq` with `min1->freq`, not `min2->freq` as you're currently doing -- and vice versa for the code inside the `else if` statement block following the second line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer for you, but I don't trust checking `temp->next->next->next!=NULL` in a while loop.  That's going to have problems with short lists.

You might be better off looking at one item at a time.  Set your two min values to maximum possible value (i.e. `INT_MAX`) and the node pointers to NULL.

- If the value of the first item on the list is less than one of your two min values, update the min value and node pointer.
- If the value of the next item on the list is less than one of your two min values, update the min value and the node pointer.  You may need to rearrange the order of the min values.
- Repeat until you've looked at every item in the list.

You should have your answer when you get to the end of the list and the pointer manipulation will be easier to trace/debug.

Comment: thanks but i couldn't understand, could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: What part do you need me to elaborate on?

Comment: It will for C++, but I don't know about C#.  Sorry.

Comment: First i intialise min1 and min2 to INT_MAX after that ?

Comment: In C# it's int.MaxValue, but the concept should be the same.

Comment: @Candlemancer Ok thanks . what library i have to include to use it in c# ?

Comment: `using System;` should be all you need, there's a page that talks more about it at [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-maxvalue)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int freq;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node node;

//Function Prototype
void find_two_min(node**, node**, node**);

void main() {
    node* min1 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* min2 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* tree = NULL;
    node* prev;
    node* temp1;
    node* temp;
    node* temp5 = tree;
    int size, data;
    int count = 0; //this count flag is to check is it's first node or not inside the do-while loop.
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", & data);
        if (count == 0) {
            temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
            tree = prev;
        } else {
            node* temp;
            temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        size--;
        ++count;
    } while (size > 0);
    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    temp1 = tree;
    while (temp1) {
        printf("%d-> ", temp1->freq);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    if (count > 1) {
        find_two_min(&tree, &min1, &min2);
        printf("\n The two minimumnumbers are  min1 :%d   and min2 : %d\n",min1->freq,min2->freq);
    } else
        printf("\n Not enough data\n\n");

}

//Function Definition
void find_two_min(node** List,node** lmin1,node** lmin2) {
    node* temp = *List;
    node* min1;
    node* min2;
    node* var1 = *List;
    node* second=(*List)->next;

    /* OLD ONE    
    if (var1->freq > second->freq) {
      min2 = var1;
      min1 = second;
    } else {
      min1 = var1;
     min2 = second;
    }
   */

   if (var1->freq > second->freq) {
      min1 = var1;
      min2 = second;
    } else {
      min2 = var1;
     min1 = second;
    }
    while(temp->next) {
        printf("\nCurrent freq is %d", temp->freq);
        printf("\nNext freq is %d", (temp->next)->freq);

        if ((temp->next)->freq < min2->freq) {
            printf("\n  Condition one is fulfilled");
            min1 = min2;
            min2 = temp->next;    
        } else if ((temp->next)->freq < min1->freq) {
            printf("\n  Condition two is fulfilled");
            min1 = temp->next;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    *lmin1 = min1; 
    *lmin2 = min2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but also sorry it don't work on the following input : "-1-> 0-> -5-> 2->" the output is " The two minimumnumbers are  min1 :0   and min2 : -5" WHICH IS WRONG.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the solution of my question using INT_MAX. It works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <limits.h>

struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * tree;

//Problem creating area is below (code for finding minimum two elements)
void find_two_min(node * * List, node * * lmin1, node * * lmin2) 
{
    node * temp = * List;
    node * min1;
    min1 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    min1 -> freq = INT_MAX;
    node * min2;
    min2 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    min2 -> freq = INT_MAX;  //This initialisation of INT_MAX to min2->freq creates problem because printf() statment above it works well but don't work below it.
    printf("check1\n");
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        printf("\ncheck2\n");       
        if ((temp) -> freq < min2 -> freq)
        {
            printf("check3\n");
            min1 = min2;
            min2 = temp;
        } 
        else if ((temp) -> freq < min1 -> freq && (temp) -> freq != min2 -> freq)
        {
            printf("check4\n");
            min1 = temp;
        }
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    * lmin1 = min1; 
    * lmin2 = min2;
    printf("address of min2 is : %d  and value is %d \n" ,min2, min2->freq);    
    printf("check5\n"); 
}
//Problem creating area is above//
void main() 
{
    int size, data;
    node * min1;
    node * min2;
    int count = 0; //this count flag is to check is it's first node or not inside the do-while loop.
    tree = NULL;
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");
    node * prev;
    do {
        scanf("%d", & data);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp -> freq = data;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
            tree = prev;
        }
        else 
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp -> freq = data;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            prev -> next = temp;
            prev = prev -> next;
        }
        size--;
        ++count;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    node * temp1;
    temp1 = tree;
    while (temp1 != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d-> ", temp1 -> freq);
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }
    node * temp5 = tree;
    find_two_min( & temp5, & min1, & min2);
    printf("\n The two minimum numbers are  min1 :%d   and min2 : %d\n", min1 -> freq, min2 -> freq);

}
```